# Is executing query in loop vs in one go at Oracle recommended for substantial performance gain?

Tags: python, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I've a Python batch job that executes a SQL query based on supplied ids. 
The number of ids is usually above 20k.

The query is:

```sql
SELECT MY_ID, COL_A, COL_B FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID IN {dynamically_set_ids}
```

Because Oracle limits the number of values in `IN` clause to 1000, I updated the query to:

```sql
WITH ids_list AS 
(select id1 AS my_id FROM dual
UNION
select id2 AS my_id FROM dual ...) -- all 20k+ ids added like this
SELECT col_a,
       col_b,
       some_table.my_id

FROM   some_table
join   ids_list
ON     ids_list.my_id = some_table.my_id
```

The above query executes in **around 33 mins.** 
But when I loop the list of ids and execute the query in a loop:

```py
con = get_con()
for i in range(calculated_iterations):
    con.execute("select my_id, col_a, col_b where my_id in {0}".format(1k_or_less_ids))
    # collect data
```

For current amount of data, the loop above returns expected data in **around 40 secs only**.

So, the question is: Is it suggested/ok to execute the select in a loop ?

The performance gain doesn't matter much as the job runs overnight.
But, for such a gain, would a loop be preferred ?

Note that amount of data cannot be guessed. It usually runs in millions of rows.

Comment: Under what conditions do you think a task taking 33 minutes would be preferable to one taking 40 seconds?

Comment: @ScottHunter When we want to limit hits to database, I guess.

Comment: How would repeated hits *that total under a minute* be worse than a single "hit" taking over 30 times longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20K  'union select all ..' statements?  Regardless of run-time performance, that is coding madness!

The 'textbook' solution is to put those 20k values in a text file, define an external table over it, then

```
SELECT MY_ID, 
       COL_A, 
       COL_B 
FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID IN (select ext_id 
                             from my_external_table)
;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify if the ids loaded from the table won't result in [ORA-01795](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/958612/ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is-1000-error) error ?

Comment: Of course not, Adarsh. They are stored in a **table**, which is very different from making an **IN** list, e.g. `in (1, 2, 4, 5, 20, 999, 1001, 20000)`. That's just not *it*.

Comment: _"Can you please clarify if the ids loaded from the table won't result in ORA-01795 error ?"_    If that were the case, it wouldn't be the "textbook solution", would it?  If you don't take my word for it, it would be a lot easier and faster for you to test it yourself that it would to write up 20k 'union select' statements.  Where do these 20k ids originate from in the first place?

Comment: If you don't have privileges or machine access to use an external table, you could first upload the data values (with `executeMany()`) to something like a global temporary table, and then using that table in the subquery.  The general reference for using multiple values in a WHERE IN clause is https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause